# How to add css class to body tag in layout in yii2?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to add css class to body tag in yii2 advanced in frontend/views/layouts/main.php how can I do it?

Comment: What you had tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this dynamically like this:

```
<body class="<?= $this->context->bodyClass; ?>">
```

And in main `Controller` (all other controllers should extend this `Controller`) define property:

```
public $bodyClass;
```

or for default value:

```
public $bodyClass = 'custom-skin';
```

Ofc you can override this property in any extending controller by redefining it:

```
public $bodyClass = 'custom-skin-2';
```

In init:

```
public function init() {
    parent::init();
    $this->bodyClass = 'custom-skin-2';
}
```

In specific action:

```
public function actionView()
{
    $this->bodyClass = 'custom-skin-3';

    return $this->render('view');
}
```

Comment: If you do this <body class="<?= $this->context->bodyClass ?? ''; ?>"> It even works without defining it on all controllers/actions

Answer (score 1):

You add your class simply to body tag

```
<body class="yourClass">
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't notice that)

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution would be using the variable `$params` in your view.

#### Example

In your view you can define:

```
$this->params['bodyClass'] = 'yourclass';
```

And then, in your layout file, you'd go:

```
[.. head and other codes ..]

<body <? if(isset($this->params['bodyClass'])) echo 'class="' . $this->params['bodyClass'] . '"'; ?>>
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>

[.. rest of your code  ..]
```

#### Notice that

I'm suggesting you to use the if so it only puts the class if it the $params['bodyClass'] is set in your view.

Also, you can use whatever name you want in the place of *bodyClass*.

This example will output `<body class="yourclass">`

Cheers.